# Render styles or link element in .net core C# code

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a method in a .net core API that uses a HTMl to PDF conversion Nuget package to create PDF files from a HTML string. To produce the PDF I simply create a string of html and pass it into a method in the conversion library.

In .net 4.5 I could include CSS files in this HTMl string by doing this (where the variable "html" is the input to display):

```
htmlToConvert = "<html class='mdzr--svg'><head>" +                            
    HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Styles.Render("~/Content/css").ToHtmlString()) +
    "</head><body>" + html +
    "</body></html>";
```

I am now trying to do a similar thing in .net core but am struggling with how to render a CSS file as there isn't the same Styles.Render functionality.

I am planning on putting the CSS file somewhere in the wwwroot of the API.

Any advice on how to access it and render it into a link element would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does `Styles.Render` do? This appears to be a very old thing that isn’t well documented.

Comment: On hovering over the method it says "Renders link tags for a set of paths". It's in System.Web.Optimization.Styles.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1), the way to do this in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1 is to configure the `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` method to set the root of the project (in their example, to the current directory; I believe the default is the `wwwroot` directory in a brand new ASP.NET Core MVC project):

`Program.cs`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Then, configure the application to use static files at startup:

`Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

Then, you can use your `<img>`, `<script>`, and `<link>` tags as you would in a normal HTML document.

More advanced options are available by following the documentation link above.

Comment: Please note I am brand new to ASP.NET Core, if you have any suggestions, please post them in the comments and I will update the answer accordingly. Thank you.